# Where's the capacitor usually located at the bottom back of fridge?

Tags: refrigerator

[This amateur](https://youtu.be/UuxA96ry3Wg?t=169) warns to steer clear of capacitor. But he fails to indicate where it usually is? Can anyone indicate please?

[image]
This second [pic](http://tech.akom.net/archives/31-Getting-your-refrigerator-to-run-without-a-start-relay-while-you-wait-for-the-part.html) doesn't answer my question, because the capacitor looks pulled out far from its USUAL location.

[image]

I know [what capacitors are supposed to look like](https://removeandreplace.com/2015/04/02/how-to-test-a-capacitor/).

[image]

Comment: Since A) you know what a capacitor looks like, and B) you haven't shown us a picture of _your_ fridge, why don't _you_ look for a capacitor in the back? With no idea whatsoever of what model fridge we've got, that's the best possible answer you could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compressor motors usually have two capacitors ; a "start" and a "run ". Sometime one or both are inside the compressor enclosure . It is pretty easy to discharge one ; In the good old days of CRT TV with vacuum tubes , I would use a plastic handle screw driver to ground them ; touch the metal shaft to a ground then slide the blade to the contact on the capacitor , or  CRT. One frequently needed to pull vacuum tubes for testing and you wanted everything discharged before pulling them out. The old CRTs had components at over 10,000 V , so you wanted everything grounded.

Answer (score 1):

Most motor capacitors are physically attached to the compressor or under a plastic cover. You don’t mention why you are looking for it but it is usually attached on the compressor or close to it physically.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to google your brand and model to look for a parts diagram. Capacitors are typically for compressors with AC motors.  Many newer refrigerators have DC motors powered an enclosed power module instead.

You can also just unplug the refrigerator and wait an hour or two for the capacitor to discharge.